# Seed script in Entity Framework Core is breaking my migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a very simple scenario where I have number of related entities and a couple of them are expected to be prefilled (through seed script). Then, I run my application and it adds a new related data (related to the tables populated by seed script).

And eventually, when I want to add a new migration, for example make a field nullable (of an entity which was not seeded), I try the `update-database` command and everything breaks up because the migration is trying to recreate my seeded tables. It is impossible because they keep a foreign key.

I will be more specific:

**Car** (Id, Brand, Color, Year)

many-to-one

**CarType** (Id, Value)

So, in my DbContext I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CarType>()
                .HasData(new CarType('4125ad9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-7e8acc097d6f', 'Coupe'))
```

And then, I run my application and I start inserting new `Car`s with the respective types. So, now I have:

```
Car(1, 'BMW', 'Black', 2011) FK-> CarType('4125ad9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-7e8acc097d6f', 'Coupe')
Car(2, 'Audi', 'Green', 2008) FK-> CarType('cc097d6f9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-4125ad7e8a', 'Estate')
```

But, one day I decide to make the `Year` field nullable

```
public int? Year { get; set; }
```

I ran `add-migration` and everything looks fine except for that in the `Up` statement:

```
migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
                table: "CarType",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: new Guid("4125ad9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-7e8acc097d6f"));
```

Once I execute `update-database` I get an error that the operation can not be executed because there's a foreign key related to the entity I am trying to delete:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

How am I supposed to handle that? My seed scrips are kind of blocking me right now. I want to be able to make changes to my other tables, even on the ones that are seed scripted without the need to recreate stuff.

Comment: @GertArnold Corrected.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to remove the **HasData** related seeding from my DbContext because when a migration is added the changes to the data specified with **HasData** are transformed to calls to **InsertData**(), **UpdateData**(), and **DeleteData**().

So, as suggested [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#manual-migration-customization), I moved the initialization logic into my initial migration.

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    table: "CarType",
    columns: new[] { "Id", "Value" },
    values: new object[] { "4125ad9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-7e8acc097d6f", "Coupe" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've records in DB depends on Card Type Id with the same Id you tried to delete
so you can manually delete all dependent entities from DB then apply update database and this not recommended
or
change all entities that have relation with CardType to be "Cascade" in onModelCreating function

example

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.CardTypes)
                .WithMany(p => p.Cards)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CardTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)   /* Cascade */
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Cards_CardTypes");
```

Comment: I don't want to delete Cars when applying a migration.

Comment: you should delete all entities that depends on this card type you tried to delete because there is relationship between these entities because migration tried to delete card type but there is constrains violated

Comment: Is it mandatory to delete an entity I am not making changes to? Isn't it possible to configure the migration somehow so it doesn't consider those?

Comment: if you still have Card Type with ID "4125ad9e-68fe-4d25-9d73-7e8acc097d6f" in your CardType table so you should delete this record and what depends on it, if not just comment DeleteData line it'll work

Comment: This is what I am doing now but I am not sure how consistent is that. I was trying to find some kind of automation for that.

Comment: if you need to avoid this don't do manual changes or delete any records manually from DB